# Differentiating the log determinant and applying the chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Suppose  $B$ is $m \times n$ and $\Sigma$ is $n \times n$ and symmetric and $B \Sigma B^T$ is also symmetric. I am trying to obtain

the following:

$$\frac{\partial \log( \det[B \Sigma B^T])}{\partial B}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial \log( \det[B \Sigma B^T])}{\partial \Sigma}$$

Now from the matrix cookbook, I know that (1)$$\frac{dlog(det(Y))}{dY} = \operatorname{tr}(Y^{-1}dY) $$.

My attempt is to use chain rule (I am not sure if my chain rule specification is correct) and applying (1):

$$\frac{\partial \log( \det[B \Sigma B^T])}{\partial B} = \frac{\partial \log( \det[B \Sigma B^T])}{\partial B\Sigma B^T} \frac{\partial B\Sigma B^T}{\partial B} 
 = \operatorname{tr}((B \Sigma B^T)^{-1})\frac{\partial B\Sigma B^T}{\partial B} $$

**Question 1:** Is my chain rule specification correct ?

**Question 2:** I do not know how to compute $\frac{\partial B \Sigma B^T}{\partial B}$

Similarly,  applying the same logic to  $\frac{\partial \log( \det[B \Sigma B^T])}{\partial \Sigma}$, which would result in the following

$$\frac{\partial \log( \det[B \Sigma B^T])}{\partial \Sigma} = \frac{\partial \log( \det[B \Sigma B^T])}{\partial B\Sigma B^T} \frac{\partial B\Sigma B^T}{\partial \Sigma} 
 = \operatorname{tr}((B \Sigma B^T)^{-1})\frac{\partial B\Sigma B^T}{\partial \Sigma} = \operatorname{tr}((B \Sigma B^T)^{-1})(B^TB)$$

**Question 3:** Is $\frac{\partial B\Sigma B^T}{\partial \Sigma} = B^TB$ correct ?

Answer (score 4):

For typing convenience, let $$M=B\Sigma B^T$$
Write the function in terms of this new matrix, and find its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \log(\det(M)) \cr\cr
df &= d\log(\det(M)) \cr
   &= d{\rm tr}(\log(M)) \cr
   &= M^{-T}:dM \cr
   &= M^{-T}:(dB\,\Sigma B^T+B\,d\Sigma\,B^T+B\Sigma\,dB^T) \cr
   &= (M^{-T}B\Sigma^T+M^{-1}B\Sigma):dB + (B^TM^{-T}B):d\Sigma \cr
}$$The colon denotes the inner/Frobenius product, which is a compact 
infix notation for the trace $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$

Thus the gradients are
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial B} &= M^{-T}B\Sigma^T+M^{-1}B\Sigma \cr
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial\Sigma} &= B^TM^{-T}B \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not get how does $ d log(det(M))$ go to $d tr (log(M))$. Can you explain please ?

Comment: $d\log M=M^{-1}d M$ if $M$ invertible, so this is just the result (1) you cite in your question. @user1769197

Comment: Yes yes. I understand now. Thanks. I am digesting the rest of the content.

Comment: Since $(\Sigma, M)$ are symmetric the gradients can be simplified further $$\eqalign{\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}&=2M^{-1}B\Sigma\cr \frac{\partial f}{\partial \Sigma}&=B^TM^{-1}B\cr}$$